# メール送信時の「Your host name dosen't match with your IP address」というエラーについて

Tags: linux, postfix, dns

bizknow1.comというドメインのサーバで、vpsneo@hanmail.net宛にphpスクリプトからメール配信しようとすると、以下のようなエラーが表示されます。

```
host mx2.hanmail.net[180.70.93.97] said: 454 5.7.1 DXNS3 133.242.155.196: Message refused. 
Your host name dosen't match with your IP address: mail.bizknow1.com 
If you need, please contact hanmailcs@daumcorp.com. (in reply to end of DATA command)
```

postfixの設定は

```
myhostname = mail.bizknow1.com
mydomain = bizknow1.com
myorigin = $mydomain
```

のようになっています。digの結果は以下のようになっています。

```
# dig mail.bizknow1.com

;; ANSWER SECTION:
mail.bizknow1.com.  14145   IN  A   133.242.155.196

# dig bizknow1.com

;; ANSWER SECTION:
bizknow1.com.       14399   IN  A   133.242.155.196

# dig -x 133.242.155.196

;; ANSWER SECTION:
196.155.242.133.in-addr.arpa. 3599 IN   PTR bizknow1.com.

# dig bizknow1.com mx

;; ANSWER SECTION:
bizknow1.com.       14399   IN  MX  10 bizknow1.com.
```

設定をどのように修正すれば、このエラーは解消するのでしょうか？

あるいは、設定は正しいけど、反映に時間がかかっているので
エラーになっているということでしょうか？

ご存知であれば教えて下さい。

Comment: `dig -x 133.242.155.196`を実行して、`mail.bizknow1.com`が返ってくれば、PTRレコードの設定はできていると思います

Answer (score 1):

Postfix では HELO/EHLO コマンドで申告するホスト名に $myhostname が使われます。
相手先 MTA で、HELO/EHLO のホスト名と、接続元IPアドレスの逆引きが合っているか検証し、合っていない場合に拒否する仕様なのだと思います。

HELO/EHLO コマンドで申告するホスト名は以下のパラメーターで設定できます。

`smtp_helo_name = bizknow1.com`

Comment: エラーが以下のようになりましたが、基本的に同じエラーが出ています。

host mx4.hanmail.net[180.70.93.98] said: 454 5.7.1 DXNS3 133.242.155.196: Message refused. 
Your host name dosen't match with your IP address: bizknow1.com 
If you need, please contact hanmailcs@daumcorp.com. (in reply to end of DATA command)

他に考えられる原因はありますでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

> Your host name dosen't match with your IP address: mail.bizknow1.com

逆引きした結果が「mail.bizknow1.com」ではないと言ってますので
PTRレコードが「mail.bizknow1.com」になるよう変更すると解決できそうに思えます。

DNSの変更はTTLの時間の間、キャッシュされますのでしばらくたってから確認してください。
変更したにも関わらず解決できない場合は、DNSに問題がある可能性が考えられます。

どうしても解決できないようであれば、相手のメールサーバの管理者に
ホワイトリスト登録をお願いするのも手です。